# Cannot write to a file - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin, xamarin.android, streamwriter

I have tried writing to a text file using both a `StreamWriter` and just `File.Write`. I cannot write to a file or create a new file.

```
using (StreamWriter Sw = new StreamWriter(assets.Open("test.txt")))
{
    Sw.WriteLine("test");
};
```

This is using xamarin on visual studio

Comment: What is `assets`? Are you using Unity?

Comment: Using visual studio, creating an android app, assets is an assetmanager

Comment: So this is for Xamarin? It would be helpful to add that information into your question!

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clarifying earlier

Comment: You should clarify it in the actual question before it gets closed...

Comment: you cannot write to files included in the Android app bundle - it is read only

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different IO libraries. One is Android.IO the other is System.IO. I have found System.IO to be more reliable when creating and writing to a file

```
if (Directory.Exists(myfilePath))
{
File.AppendAllText(myfilePath + "\\" + MyFileName + ".txt", "Testing ......");
            }
            else
            {

                Directory.CreateDirectory(myfilePath);
                File.AppendAllText(myfilePath + "\\" + MyFileName + ".txt", "Testing ......");
            }
```

The only thing is I can not read the file contents. I'm trying to see if anyone RECENTLY has had success with reading the file's contents.